# how can i read last 2 bytes from file and delete them after read

Tags: c, file

Here i developed on program for `CRC 16` for file verification

Here i calculated CRC 16 of file and write this `CRC` value at the end of file. crc value data type is `unsigned short` so its take 2 bytes.

Code is here for that

```
void appendCRCtoFile(const char* filePath, unsigned short result) {
        FILE *readFile;
        //open a file for Reading
        readFile = fopen(filePath, "ab");
        fseek(readFile, SEEK_END, SEEK_SET);
        const unsigned char check_bytes[2] = { result >> 8, result & 255 };
        const size_t wrote = fwrite(check_bytes, 1, sizeof(check_bytes), readFile);
        if (wrote == 2) {
            printf("succesfull wrote 2 bytes\n");

        } else {
            printf("Failed to wrote 2 bytes\n");
        }
        fclose(readFile);
    }
```

Now i have to read these last two bytes from the file and want to delete them after read and again want to calculate CRC. so how can i read these last two bytes and delete them after read.

Comment: `fseek(readFile, SEEK_END, SEEK_SET);` is likely wrong. Use `fseek(readFile, 0, SEEK_END);` instead ...

Comment: There is no standard way to remove bytes from a file. You either have to copy the file (minus the unwanted data), or use some OS specific functions.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to `rewind` the file two bytes back.

```
fseek(readFile, -2, SEEK_CUR);
```

Comment: Thanks For Your Reply Its not Working