# Remove Last two bytes from the File or Ignore last two bytes of the file In C

Tags: c, file

Here i am implementing CRC 16 for file for file verification.

Here i append 2 bytes CRC at the end of file. When File will be received on target device than i have  to calculate CRC of this file without last two bytes

Here is my data after appeneding CRC at the end of file.

```
test123
wU
```

Now when i again calculate CRC on target device than i want to ignore last two bytes.
Here i have one common function in which i open file in read mode and calculate CRC. i want to use same function for this time.
I have one solution make another function same like previous one and go up to `filesize-2`. but dnt want to replicate function two times. i want to delete last two bytes.

So any body have Suggestion or Solution regarding this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can i read last 2 bytes from file and delete them after read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600083/how-can-i-read-last-2-bytes-from-file-and-delete-them-after-read)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your function take a parameter to ignore the last n bytes.  Pass in 0 for normal use a 2 for that case.

Comment: Ya Its perfect but i have one another function for decryption for that i have also ignore this two bytes? so its hectic for me. so please Suggest me way if we can delete last two bytes

Answer (score 3):

In addition, do you need help truncating two bytes off a file?

What kind of API is on the target.

On POSIX you can `open` the file, then `off_t pos = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END)` to seek to the end, which returns the position. if `(pos == (off_t) -1)` then the call failed. If the call succeeded, you can just `ftruncate(fd, pos - 2)` (provided that `pos >= 2`).

Comment: ftruncate use for delete bytes?

Comment: I cant understand Your Answer..Can u please Explain me in breif

Comment: The ftruncate function will set the length of a file to a given length, with byte precision. It can make a file longer, or shorter. If the file is made shorter, the tail portion of it is removed. If you need to remove the CRC from the file without making a copy of the file (and you have these functions), you can do it that way.

Comment: Please provide me Example of ftruncate